# Shiny: is it possible to have save each users' activities

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am in the brain storming stage of a shiny app. What I want to develop is an app that allows users to answer a series of questions for risk assessments. However, once of the key functions for this app is to allow the users to save their unfinished assessments and come back later to resume. I would like to find out if it is possible to achieve this in shiny.

Comment: best way is to save it in the database, are you connected to any of the DBs?

Comment: @PorkChop I'm still in the design stage,but there will be a database on shiny server. Given that, I think the really challenge is how to allow users to resume the assessment when they come back.

Comment: You simply create user profiles in the database and then query the previously saved results from it, if the exist ofc. Designing table schemas isn't that difficult for your example